# Android Library / Application Design

Tags: android

So I have an interesting question more or less to the high level design of using Android Libraries vs product flavors vs product variants etc.

Right now my problem is that I am trying to build a second Android application (after building my first) one where in many cases I can reuse a majority of my non UI code (IE activities, styles etc.) and reuse a small portion of the UI code.

Right now I see two different strategies, one being make a new application + Android library for the shared code (resulting in basically my POV two new GIT repos along with two corresponding projects) or take my original application and write a few productFlavor / productVariants and sort of tweak things as needed (this would allow me not to have to make two new GIT repos + project setups).

What do folks usually do in this situation?

Update:

Maybe a project with each submodule would work best as separate apps while moving the central library (shared code) to a library module.